# Test case is freezing my system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to run one test case and it is freezing my system. I am not able to figure it out. It is not even giving me an error, just freezing my system.

```
describe "GET /edit" do
    context "when in client portal" do
      it "renders successfully" do
        get "/admin/aniket_accounts/#{account.to_param}/edit", nil
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: why are you passing nil? put a binding.pry in your action to check what is going wrong

Comment: Try to pass `{}` in `get` method instead of `nil`